# Using python3, I would like to get file name, file size, and file creation date for all files within a specific date range

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, range

My goal is to output name, date and size of files for the specific time period of a month. I have managed to get 3 out of 4. My output provides the name, date, and size of file but does not limit it to a specific month, instead generating output for all files in a folder.

This is what I have so far

```
#get file sizes within date range 

import os 
import datetime  

start = datetime.datetime.strptime("2021-02-01", "%Y-%m-%d") 
end = datetime.datetime.strptime("2021-02-28", "%Y-%m-%d")   

file = (start + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, (end-start).days)) 

def span(ts):  
 return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%b %d, %Y')  

for file in os.scandir('/Users/axr25/Desktop/testBag/'): 
 print(file.name, span(file.stat().st_atime), file.stat().st_size)
```

Output for the script from the 'testBag' folder noted is as follows:

```
axr25@L5-PC4-PRES-1 myscripts % python3 fileSize_dateRange.py

bagit.txt Jan 27, 2021 55

bag-info.txt Jan 27, 2021 162

.DS_Store Feb 17, 2021 6148

manifest-sha512.txt Jan 27, 2021 705

tagmanifest-sha256.txt Sep 10, 2020 323

tagmanifest-sha512.txt Sep 10, 2020 579

diskGrowth.sh Feb 17, 2021 299

data Aug 29, 2020 192

manifest-sha256.txt Jan 27, 2021 449

axr25@L5-PC4-PRES-1 myscripts %
```

The information returned is for all files inside the 'testBag' folder, but I was trying to specify only February. Any suggestions on how to correct this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, taking a quick glance at it - the only code that will really matter (or be run) is this

```
for file in os.scandir('/Users/axr25/Desktop/testBag/'): 
 print(file.name, span(file.stat().st_atime), file.stat().st_size)
```

which will list all files in your directory.